# Angularjs gives back wrong response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an problem with the response in the in the registration controller.
For some reason the result is always register Failed even when the user is saved to the database. Why does this happen. I'm kinda new to angularjs - spring and does not see why this happen ?

user.service.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('UserService', UserService);

    UserService.$inject = ['$http'];
    function UserService($http) {
        var service = {};

        service.Create = Create;


        return service;

        function Create(user) {

            console.log(user.password)
            console.log(user.lastName)
            console.log(user.email)
            console.log(user.firstName)
            console.log(user.customfield)

            return $http.post('/api/register', user)
        }

})();
```

And register.Controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

    RegisterController.$inject = ['UserService', '$location', '$rootScope' ];
    function RegisterController(UserService, $location, $rootScope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.register = register;

        function register() {
            vm.dataLoading = true;
            UserService.Create(vm.user)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {

                        console.log("register Succeed")

                        //FlashService.Success('Registration successful', true);
                        $location.path('/home');

                    } else {

                        console.log("register Failed")
                        vm.dataLoading = false;
                    }
                });
        }
    }

})();
```

register.html

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="RegisterController as vm">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <div ng-show="vm.error" class="alert alert-danger">{{vm.error}}</div>
        <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.register()" role="form">


            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.lastName.$dirty && form.lastName.$error.required }">
                <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.lastName" required />
                <span ng-show="form.lastName.$dirty && form.lastName.$error.required" class="help-block">Last name is required</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.firstname.$dirty && form.firstname.$error.required }">
                <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.firstName" required />
                <span ng-show="form.firstName.$dirty && form.firstName.$error.required" class="help-block">First name is required</span>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.customfield.$dirty && form.customfield.$error.required }">
                <label for="customfield">Custom field</label>
                <input type="text" name="customfield" id="customfield" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.customfield" required />
                <span ng-show="form.customfield.$dirty && form.customfield.$error.required" class="help-block">customfield is required</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
                <label for="email">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.email" required />
                <span ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$error.required" class="help-block">email is required</span>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.password" required />
                <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                <a href="#/login" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

You are testing `response.success`, which isn't a property the documentation says exists. Look at `status` instead.

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called.

Comment: Could you illustrate with an example on how i can use an if statement when the user is successful insert into the database.

Comment: Here's a basic example of what Quentin has referred to and how it works:
http://jsbin.com/gogesajogi/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

As for the testing of the success of a angular promise, you don't need to check with the if statement. The then function of the promise has to arguments (functions), the first for the success of the call and the second for failure, as in:

```
 UserService.Create(vm.user)
    .then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available, i.e. success
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```